# How to use two different email addresses for emails sending?

Tags: python, django, email, django-email

I have a Django project which has two domains.

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
```

I use `Sites` application to differ between those two addresses like:

```
<h1>Welcome to {% if site.id==1 %}Domain1{% else %}Domain2</h1>
```

I want to be able to send messages from both emails:

```
    send_email(user, 'domain1@gmail.com' if site.id==1 else 'domain2@gmail.com', message...)
```

I tried add `from_email` to `EmailMessage` but it doesn't work. Sender is 'domain1@gmail.com'.

```
mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email='domain2@gmail.com', to=[user_email])
mail.send()
```

I have only one `settings.py` so I can set probably only one SMTP.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'domain1@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pswd'
```

Do you know how to make it work?

EDIT: So I tried this:

```
with get_connection(
        host=settings.EMAIL_HOST,
        port=settings.EMAIL_PORT,
        username='myemail@gmail.com',
        password='mypasswd',
        use_tls=settings.EMAIL_USE_TLS) as connection:
    EmailMessage(subject, message, [user.email],
                 connection=connection).send()
```

I've checked it - this code is being called. It doesn't return any Exception but it doesn't send email.

To be sure, I've tested this address and email inside `settings.py` as a global connection and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the settings in your settings.py by using get_connection like this

```
from django.core.mail import get_connection, send_mail
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage

with get_connection(
    host=<host>, 
    port=<port>, 
    username=<username>, 
    password=<password>, 
    use_tls=<True/False>
) as connection:
    EmailMessage(subject, body, from, [to],
                 connection=connection).send()
```

Using with will close the connection automatically. If you don't use with you'll need to close the connection manually with `connection.close()`

Documentation is here -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#email-backends

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't work. It doesn't return any Exception but it doesn't send any email.  I've added my code at the bottom of the question. I'm sure it is called and I'm sure the credentials are ok.

Comment: Strange, I've used this in a project I worked on recently and it worked there.

Comment: Ok, now it works. I think I didn't change anything... It was probably gmail which caused the problem. As usual...

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help out.